# getting newest date from table using linq

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a table which holds fuel price data for a variety of fuel types.
Each row has an id, date, and there are 5 columns for the different fuel types.
I am having trouble coming up with a linq query to determine the date of the last row of data for each fuel type where the value isnt 0 (if a row was inserted and no fuel price was available for a specific fuel type, the value inserted for that fuel type is zero as the cells are not nullable).

I tried using LastorDefault but that wont work as sometimes the last date for a specific type isnt in the last row in the table.

Comment: Is your primary key auto-generated (e.g. Identity column)? You can sort by primary key DESC and then use .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Rui, That is what I came up with also prior to your post but thank you for commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to device a linq (and SQL) query for it. But handling denormalized stuff with a language that is made for normalized structures usually becomes a jumble of repetitive nested statements (and a less than efficient query plan). You will have repetitions anyway, so I would keep them as simple as possible by using a regular foreach:

```cs
var result = new FuelPriceSummary();
foreach(var price in context.FuelPriceData.OrderBy(p => p.Date).ToList())
{
    if (price.Price1 > 0)
        {result.Price1 = price.Price1; result.Date1 = price.date;}
    if (price.Price2 > 0)
        {result.Price2 = price.Price2; result.Date2 = price.date;}
    if (price.Price3 > 0)
        {result.Price3 = price.Price3; result.Date3 = price.date;}
    if (price.Price4 > 0)
        {result.Price4 = price.Price4; result.Date4 = price.date;}
    if (price.Price5 > 0)
        {result.Price5 = price.Price5; result.Date5 = price.date;}
}
```

If you can, normalize your database design. It will make querying a lot easier.